# MySQL cannot create procedure

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a procedure to (take as arguments a new class name, type, country, number of guns, bore, and displacement. Add this information to classes and also add the ship with the class name to ships)

Relations:

```
classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)
ships(name, class, launched)


mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE addClass(in VARCHAR(50) inClassName, in VARCHAR(5) inType, in
VARCHAR(50) inCountry, in INT inNumGuns, in INT inBore, in INT inDis)
-> begin
-> INSERT INTO classes VALUES(inClassName, inType, inCountry, inNumGuns, inBore, inDis);
-> INSERT INTO ships VALUES(inClassName, inClassName, NULL);
-> end
-> //
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(50)
inClassName, in VARCHAR(50) inType, in VARCHAR(50) inCountry, in INT' at line 1
```

I am not sure as to the source of this error, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input variable names come before their data types, not after as you have specified them:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE addClass(
  in inClassName VARCHAR(50),
  in inType VARCHAR(5) , 
  in inCountry VARCHAR(50), 
  in inNumGuns INT,
  in inBore INT,
  in inDis INT
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO classes VALUES(inClassName, inType, inCountry, inNumGuns, inBore, inDis);
  INSERT INTO ships VALUES(inClassName, inClassName, NULL);
END
```

[From the `CREATE PROCEDURE` docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html), the spec looks like

```
proc_parameter:
    [ IN | OUT | INOUT ] param_name type
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct your syntax. Here is an example:

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE addClass(in inClassName VARCHAR(50),
in inType VARCHAR(5), in inCountry VARCHAR(50),
in inNumGuns INT, in inBore INT, in inDis INT)

begin

INSERT INTO classes VALUES(inClassName, inType, inCountry, inNumGuns, inBore, inDis);
INSERT INTO ships VALUES(inClassName, inClassName, NULL);

end//

delimiter ;
```